# Symfony2 - Is it possible to create a standalone collection of forms?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a table of data I want to be able to edit row-by-row.  The most sensible thing do do would be to have each row be its own form.  Can I do that in Symfony2 *without* a linked parent entity?  The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) only shows how to do it with a parent.

Comment: Hello, you does not have to use `data_class` at all you can works on array... but I not sure I am get it right... please tell what do you mean by 'linked parent entity' ?

Comment: Read the link I provided above.  There, Task is essentially a parent of Tags.  In my case, I just want a form for each Tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action:

```
    public function gridAction( $criteria ) {
        $entities = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository( 'Bundle:Entity' )
        ->findbyCriteria( $criteria );
        // criteria presumably involves some gneration from routing 
        // and may not be a parameter at all

        if ( array() != $entities->toArray() ) {
            throw 
            $this->createNotFoundException( 'Unable to find any entities.' );
        }

        $forms = array_map(function($element) use ($this) {
            return $this->createForm(new EntityType()
                , $element
                , array()  // form parameters here
                );
        });

        return $this->render( 'Bundle:Entity:grid.html.twig'
            , array(
                'forms'          => $forms
            ) );
    }
```

And your twig:

```
<table class="records_list dataTable" id="CaseloadTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for form in forms %}
        <tr>
            {{form_widget(form)}}
        </tr>   
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, you might be better served looking at this:
https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle